# Radio Button Conflict between Bootstrap And Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h2>Radio Button Conclict between Bootstrap And Angular</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <!-- With data-toggle -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <div class="row">
        <h4 class="col-lg-12">
          This has data-toggle property
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group row" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection" name="options" value="option1" />
          <span>Option 1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection" name="options" value="option2" />
          <span>Option 2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection" name="options" value="option3" />
          <span>Option 3</span>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <p>Model: {{selection | json}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/ With data-toggle -->

    <!-- Without data-toggle -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <div class="row">
        <h4 class="col-lg-12">
          This has NOT data-toggle property
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group row">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection2" name="options" value="option1" />
          <span>Option 1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection2" name="options" value="option2" />
          <span>Option 2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection2" name="options" value="option3" />
          <span>Option 3</span>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <p>Model: {{selection2 | json}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/ Without data-toggle -->

  </div>

</div>
<!--/ Container -->
```

" data-toggle="buttons" " tag does not allow the angular js to work properly as u can u see in this plnkr example too.. but if i remove then its working fine..

but i want ot keep it as it is..

http://plnkr.co/edit/l36UgnR7kltphXdEQLCk?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By hiding the radio buttons using the `data-toggle="button"` attribute on the `btn-group`, bootstrap is not allowing the click event to propagate down to the radio input. You can counter this effect by adding `ng-click` bindings to the `.btn` elements.

```
<div class="btn-group row" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="selection = 'option1'">
      <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection" name="options" value="option1" />
      <span>Option 1</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="selection = 'option2'">
      <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection" name="options" value="option2" />
      <span>Option 2</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="selection = 'option3'">
      <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection" name="options" value="option3" />
      <span>Option 3</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

PS. the reason you'll notice that clicking the top set of `radio` affects the bottom set is because they have the same `name` attribute. Change this as needed and you'll notice that each group works correctly/independently of the other

Answer (score -1):

Because of same name for input this is happening.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h2>Radio Button Conclict between Bootstrap And Angular</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <!-- With data-toggle -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <div class="row">
        <h4 class="col-lg-12">
          This has data-toggle property
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group row" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection" name="group1" value="option1" />
          <span>Option 1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection" name="group1" value="option2" />
          <span>Option 2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection" name="group1" value="option3" />
          <span>Option 3</span>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <p>Model: {{selection | json}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/ With data-toggle -->

    <!-- Without data-toggle -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <div class="row">
        <h4 class="col-lg-12">
          This has NOT data-toggle property
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group row">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection2" name="options" value="option1" />
          <span>Option 1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection2" name="options" value="option2" />
          <span>Option 2</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" data-ng-model="selection2" name="options" value="option3" />
          <span>Option 3</span>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <p>Model: {{selection2 | json}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/ Without data-toggle -->

  </div>

</div>
<!--/ Container -->
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/chzO8o7gx2STGkyQ8SNK?p=preview